# Displaying data on one row rather than multiple rows on datagridview (Stream reader)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, streamreader

is there any way I could display a data to the datagrid view Columns through depending on the value of a cell. I was working for a program relating a time and attendance system that would disperse the data from the csv file to the correct data column on the datagrid view. What I want to display is the time in and time out of the specific employee in one row, but what was happening was the time in and time out creates 2 row (1 for the time in and 1 for the time out)

```
Dim sline As String = ""
Do
sline = csvreader.ReadLine
    If sline Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    Dim columns() As String = sline.Split(",")
    Dim row As DataRow = datatable.NewRow
    Try

        row("Employee Number") = columns(0)
        If columns(2) = "IN" Then
            row("In Date") = columns(1)
        ElseIf columns(2) = "OUT" Then
            row("Out Date") = columns(1)
        End If
        row("In Location") = "PAM"
        row("Out Location") = "PAM"
        Dim d As String
        d = Convert.ToDateTime(columns(1)).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
        row("Shift Starttime") = d + " " + "9:00"
        row("ShiftEndTime") = d + " " + "18:00"
        row("Attendance Date") = d
        row("Time Zone") = 150
        datatable.Rows.Add(row)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

Loop
csvreader.Close()
DataGridView1.DataSource = datatable
Me.Text = datatable.Rows.Count & "rows"

Here what i want achieve is:

id          Time in                     Time out    
1234        2019-8-12 08:05:10          2019-8-12 17:05:10           
1234        2019-8-13 08:05:10          2019-8-13 17:05:10 

What is currently happening is

id          Time in                     Time out    
1234        2019-8-12 08:05:10                     
1234                                    2019-8-12 17:05:10 
1234        2019-8-13 08:05:10           
1234                                    2019-8-13 17:05:10
```

Comment: You need to use a bit of logic.  You expect every one row in the table to contain text from two rows read from the file.  The code you have reads one line from the file for every one row it adds to the table.  The solution is simple, logically speaking.  So, your task is consider that logic and then make an attempt to implement it in code.  If you make that attempt and it fails, that would be the time to post a question here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to read the CSV into first `DataTable`, then process it into 2nd `DataTable` and set the 2nd one as a `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`. It's the easiest and perhaps most clean way to do it.

Here is a simplified example to start with:

```
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable   ' input CSV table
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable   ' processed table
    dt2.Columns.Add("ClockDate", GetType(Date))
    dt2.Columns.Add("TimeIn", GetType(DateTime))
    dt2.Columns.Add("TimeOut", GetType(DateTime))

    ' create clock dates
    For Each dr In dt1.Rows
        For ir = 0 To dt2.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim dr2 As DataRow = dt2.Rows(ir)
            If dr2("ClockDate") = CDate(dr("ClockDateTime")) Then
                ' If there is an existing row for the date
                If CStr(dr("ClockType")) = "OUT" Then
                    dr2("TimeOut") = dr("ClockDateTime")
                Else
                    dr2("TimeIn") = dr("ClockDateTime")
                End If
                Exit Sub   ' break the loop and to the next input record
            End If
            If ir = dt2.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                ' you'll get here only if no row was found
                If CStr(dr("ClockType")) = "OUT" Then
                    dt2.Rows.Add({CDate(dr("ClockDateTime")), Nothing, dr("ClockDateTime")})
                Else
                    dt2.Rows.Add({CDate(dr("ClockDateTime")), dr("ClockDateTime"), Nothing})
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

And set it to `DataGridView`:

```
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt2
```

I used a bit simplified or modified syntax for clarity, i.e. your `column(2)` is `dr("ClockType")`.